# Update react state every second

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a sorting algorithm visualizer, and i'm stuck on rendering the new state each second.

Here is what i did, I have a function `bubbleSort` which perform a bubble sort on an array, called when the user clicks on a button start

```
const bubbleSort = () => {
setSorting(true)
console.log(sorting)
let attemp = 10
let temp = 0
let counter = 1
while(attemp > 0){
  attemp = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < data.datasets[0].data.length - 1; i++) {
    if(data.datasets[0].data[i] > data.datasets[0].data[i+1]){
      const newBars = data
      var interval = setInterval(() => {
        setData(swap(newBars, i, i + 1));
      }, 500 * i * counter)
    }
}
  counter++
}

//clearInterval(interval)
}
```

the swap function

```
const swap = (arr, i, j) => {
 console.log(i, j)
 let temp = arr.datasets[0].data[i];
 arr.datasets[0].data[i] = arr.datasets[0].data[j];
 arr.datasets[0].data[j] = temp;
 return arr
}
```

and my data have this shape

```
const sortData = {
labels: ['','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
datasets: [
  {
    label:  `${sortNames[sort]} sort`,
    backgroundColor: [
      chartColors.default,
      chartColors.default,
      chartColors.default,
      chartColors.default
    ], 
    borderWidth: 1,
    hoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    hoverBorderColor: '#0a2ea9',
    barPercentage:1,
    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 70, 72, 89, 23, 11, 4, 92, 87, 84, 50, 57, 59, 44, 49, 39, 35, 32, 0]
  }
]
}
```

ps: I've tried to do it using setTimeout, the same thing happens.
The sort is bieng performed but it seems `setData` is not executed, because the code below executes only once

```
useEffect(() => {
 console.log('updated')
}, [])
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing.

Comment: just visualize the data, react will take care of when it needs to get updated.. you don't have to check or maintain except for state... react is the thing to make things reactive..

Comment: check this code : https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-lamport-d9p7b?file=/src/App.js:0-467 , this is freshly baked right now for you... this example demonstrate how react-state works mainly.. and you'll be able to get a good view to react's reactive-ness.. if you have another question, fire away..

Comment: it's a sorting algorithm, I want to update the state after each step

Comment: Well your useEffect snippet only runs once because you passed in the empty array. Doing that says “run again when these things (in the empty array, which is nothing) change”. Since there’s nothing in there, useEffect isn’t watching any state for changes, so it only runs once.

Comment: @lyes, it will update in **each and every** step, just image in a fast and slow computer time of execution isn't equal, you can create another trigger to maintain to go to next step..

Comment: This post explains how to use `setInterval` with `useEffect` hook: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the second argument which will cause the `useEffect` to be triggered if the value of that second argument is changed.

```
useEffect(() => {
 console.log('updated')
}, [data])
```